# status code must be a number Error on POST request tsoa typescrpt

Tags: typescript, swagger, koa, tsoa

I am experimenting `tsoa` for rest API. But I always got the following error for `post` request.

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: status code must be a number
      at Object.set status [as status] (PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/koa/lib/response.js:87:5)
      at Object.status (PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/delegates/index.js:92:31)
      at Object.<anonymous> (PROJECT_PATH/src/rest/routes.ts:93:31)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at PROJECT_PATH/src/rest/routes.ts:8:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (PROJECT_PATH/src/rest/routes.ts:4:12)
      at RegisterRoutes.router.post (PROJECT_PATH/src/rest/routes.ts:84:43)
      at dispatch (PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
      at PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/koa-router/lib/router.js:353:16
```

The sample code is as below

```
  @Post()
  public async createUser(@BodyProp() requestBody: UserInput): Promise<void> {
    console.log(requestBody)
    // code
    this.setStatus(201);
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```

In my `tsoa.json` config I add `"middleware": "koa",` since I use `kao`.

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Looks like the first part is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same error. I managed to fix it by adding the [koa-bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser) middleware. It ensures the http body is added to the koa `ctx.request` object.

I couldn't find any mention of this in the `tsoa` docs.

Example code:

```js
    @Post('')
    public async handleRequest (
        @Request() req: Request,
        @BodyProp('param_1') param1: number
    ): Promise<void> {
        // These will all print out the http body
        console.log(param1)
        console.log(req.body)
        console.log(req.ctx.request.body)
    }
```